# Check if object array contains boolean true/false

Tags: javascript

I have a object of arrays where each array by default is [false,false] and it corresponds with a checkbox that has a yes and no option. If the user checks yes the array will update to [true,false], if the user answers no then the array will update [false, true].

Visual representation of my object

```
Object
   |
   |-> 1 
       |-> [false,false]
   |-> 2 
       |-> [false,false]
...
```

I have tried the following but it isn't what I need because it doesn't seem to check the second index of the array.

```
  for (var idx = 1; idx <=6  ; idx++)   {
    if (DataObj[idx].indexOf(true))
    {
      console.log("Not Answered");
    }
    else 
    {
      console.log("Answered");
    }
```

Code output

```
[true, false]
Answered
[false, true]
Not Answered
```

Expected output

```
[true, false]
Answered
[false, true]
Answered
[false, false]
Not answered
```

I have also tried `($.inArray(true, DataObj[idx]))` but this isn't working or I'm missing something. Am I in the right direction?

Comment: please add the object in plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately used the following as a solution

```
  for (var idx = 1; idx <=6  ; idx++)   {
    qcomplete = qcomplete + (surveyDataObj[idx][0] ? 1 : 0);
    qcomplete = qcomplete + (surveyDataObj[idx][1] ? 1 : 0);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `$.inArray(item, array)` and `Array.prototype.indexOf(item)` returns the index of the item in the array if found, or -1 otherwise. `if (a.indexOf(x))` only checks if the index is zero or not. You have to check if the index is not `-1`, or is at least zero:

```
for (var idx = 1; idx <=6  ; idx++)   {
    if (DataObj[idx].indexOf(true) >= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently only checking to see if 'true' is in the array if it is it will only return the FIRST index of true, you could get creative with lastIndexOf(true)
but the logic might start getting hairy

You also need to add a little check in your indexOf() it either return -1 or the index so a -1 means its not there:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Better yet, you can loop through that array as looping through your object like so:

```
  for (var idx = 1; idx <=6  ; idx++)   {
    var array = DataObj[idx];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      // here you will loop through the entire array and see both 'i' indexes
    }
    if (DataObj[idx].indexOf(true) > -1) // you need to do this here as well
    {
      console.log("Not Answered");
    }
    else 
    {
      console.log("Answered");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) as callback.

```js
var object = { 0: [true, false], 1: [false, true], 2: [false, false] };

document.write(Object.keys(object).map(function (k) {
    return object[k].some(Boolean) ? 'Answered' : 'Not answered';
}).join('<br>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` function and `logic OR` (`||`)

```js
var j = { 1: [true, false], 2: [false, true], 3: [false, false] };

var r = Object.keys(j).map(e => j[e].reduce((p, c) => p || c, false));

document.write(r.map(e => e ? ' Answered' : ' Not answered '))
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to use jQuery.

```js
var a = {
  a1: [false, false]
};

$("#b1").change(function() {                 // <-- when checkbox status is changing
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    a.a1[0]=true;
    a.a1[1]=false;
    $("body").append(JSON.stringify(a.a1));  // <-- just for the output
  }else{
    a.a1[0]=false;
    a.a1[1]=true;
    $("body").append(JSON.stringify(a.a1));  // <-- just for the output
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="b1" type="checkbox"></input>
```